# C#: Generic method expression with unknown signature

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda, generic-programming

For example we have a generic method

```
public void Test<T>(T param, Action<T> callback)
{

}
```

If call this method with some parameter, it automatically detect the type of T and we don't need to declare it explicitly.

For example:

```
// here 'int' detected
Test(1, (intVariable) =>
{

});

// here 'string' detected
Test("hello", (stringVariable) =>
{

});
```

Now, is there any possible way to do the same with methods. For example

```
Test(int.Parse, (parseMethod) =>
{
    parseMethod("11");
});
```

Yes, method/s with the same name can have different signatures and it's impossible to detect which one you want to use as a parameter, but maybe something close possible.

Comment: I don't think so, because in your particular example you want to use static methods that are called the same but with different returning type. I do not think that is possible, although there might be some C# magic I don't recall now

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Does `int.Parse` have some relationship to `parseMethod`? Does `parseMethod` return anything? What will you do with the return value? Where does `"11"` come from?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want this to do. Why not just call `int.Parse("11")`? Can you describe with some more detail the problem you're trying to solve here? Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @RufusL, I need method name in some global generic method, without writing nameof() every time. For example Test<Func<Func<string, int>>>(() => int.Parse); in this case it works great if param is Expression<T>, but here I'm explicitly write the signature of method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly cast to `Func<string, int>` to make this work:

```
Test((Func<string, int>)int.Parse, (parseMethod) =>
{
    parseMethod("11");
});
```